# Can I use New-Symlink on UNC paths?

Tags: powershell, symlink, unc, pscx

I am trying to create a symlink to a file on Windows using PowerShell. I am using the `New-Symlink` cmdlet from the PowerShell Community Extensions.

After struggling to figure out the syntax of `New-Symlink` I was able to get it to work correctly on my local drive. However, I am trying to get it to work on a file share and when I run the command there, I get this output

```
[PC-KHARPER] <~>$ New-Symlink '\\nyprodfs01\profiles$\kharper\testDir\testFile2' '\\nyprodfs01\profiles$\kharper\testFile'
New-Symlink : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
At line:1 char:1
+ New-Symlink '\\nyprodfs01\profiles$\kharper\testDir\testFile2' '\\nyprodfs01\pro ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Microsoft.Power...stDir\testFile2:UnresolvedPscxPathImpl) [New-Symlink], Unauthoriz
   edAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateSymbolicLinkError,Pscx.Commands.IO.Ntfs.NewSymlinkCommand
```

Is this expected output for UNC paths? Or should it be working and I'm just doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure if it supports the target being another UNC path, but making a symlink on windows requires elevated permissions. 

* Is your script running elevated?
* Does the elevated user have admin privileges on the target path?

Comment: I am running an elevated prompt, but I don't have admin privileges on the fileserver.

Comment: Tried with someone who has admin rights on the box, but it still doesn't work. No error message, but no success either.

Comment: I do have the exact same error when doing something like `New-Symlink C:\path\to\link \\path\to\target\directory` while `mklink /D  C:\path\to\link \\path\to\target\directory` works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the symlink support that comes with PS5 (which came out well after this question was posted) then you can mount a symlink to a UNC share.

`[host]: PS> New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path <localpath> -Value \\<uncpath>`

There is a problem if you need to pass credentials as New-Item doesn't take creds. The workaround I use is to mount a PSDrive to the folder and then symlink the PSDrive.

`[host]: PS> New-PSDrive Z FileSystem \\<uncpath> -Credential <cred>
[host]: PS> New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path <path> -Value Z:\`